# Python, find the index of 1D array that is filled with arrays of tuple

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, tuples

I have a 1D array. each element holds a unique value IE [2013 12 16 1 10] so array[0,0] would be [2013] array[0,1] would be [12]. array[0,0:2] would be [2013 12].

When I try array.index(array[0,0:5]). It creates error and says that list indicies must be integers, not tuple. find the index of a specific element if the element is [2013 12 16 1 10] a tuple...?

Comment: You say you have a 1-d array, but you use 2 indices. Why is that? Also, it looks like you have a list, not any sort of array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1D array, then array[0,0] is invalid. Try this link:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/python-array/

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a 1D array, you do:

```
my_array = [2013, 12, 16, 1, 10]
```

position for 2013 would be:

```
my_array[0]
```

I you want to do: my_array[0,0], then you need: `my_array = [[2013, 12, 16, 1, 10]]

Also check the link posted by: Musfiqur rahman

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1 dimensional array, that is simply an array of values like you mentioned where the array could equal `[2013, 12, 16, 1, 10]`. You access individual items in the array by using array[index]. However, there are actually 3 parameters used for getting array values:

`array[start:end:step]`

array[0, 1] is invalid, as the syntax is using colons not commas. 0,1 evaluates to a tuple of 2 values, `(0, 1)`. If you want to get the value of 12, you need to say `array[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are talking about a 1D array then you must do the following:

```
myArray = [44, 62, 2013, 2, 1, 10]
#the position for 62 would be:
myArray[1]
```

Then if you want to get a few values from your array you should you ":" not ",". For example:

```
myArray = [44, 62, 2013, 2, 1, 10]
#the position for 62, 2013, 2, 1 would be:
myArray[1:4]
```